# Perl regex question

Tags: regex, perl

How can I execute some code inside regex replace, for example, replace something by a new random number several times?

Comment: When you say "regex", you mean "substitution operator" (or `s///` for short).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example, `s/foo/rand()/e;`.